# Big problem: Complete computer crash (no response when booted)

Tags: 12.04, reboot, iso

I need your help:

1. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer (I removed the complete system and installed Ubuntu instead)
2. It said that the `bootloader installation failed`. So I chose the only partition that existed again.
3. `Installation succesful. Restart your computer.` I did this.
4. Then it went black when it rebooted (only a flickering stroke appears).
5. No ISOs are executable.
6. `BIOS` > `Boot Device Priority` says: `1st Boot Device        [SATA:PM-SAMSUNG HM]`
   That was all I can say, please help me!

Comment: Can you boot with the Ubuntu live CD or USB in a live session(`try Ubuntu` option)? If you can then please provide the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: No, sadly I can't: It doesn't boot at all.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to boot from CD enter BIOS settings and look for Boot/Boot device priority option and then choose your CD drive as first boot device. Or alternateively you and press `F12` when computer starts and choose your boot device as CD/DVD drive. You have to burn the `.iso` file to a CD/DVD first if you have not done it yet.

Comment: Your first boot device is set to hard-disk, change it to CD/DVD drive

Comment: @Samik: Thank you! It worked with `F12`! I'm glad that the community has members like you, Samik! If I could, I would vote you up hundred times.

Comment: Glad that helped, but is your booting problem solved, too? I mean can you now boot to your Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Yes, I can. I installed 12.04 and am happy with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot into BIOS first to find out from which device the machine trys to boot. Then boot from CD or USB again to check what is on the HD.